# Category descriptions in reponse are too vague

Tags: here-api

If you request a bakery using discover/search api, matches are returned with a general category, eg "Food and Drink".  Could the full category-id be returned with reponse? Eg, 600-6300-0244 in the case of bakery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the parameter &cs=pds you will get further information back e.g. also the category-id.

Comment: adding this parameter breaks the expected response slightly (a categories array is returned instead of a category object), but easily dealt with.  just a heads up for those using the discovery/search api.  appreciate the quick reply.